# Setting the values of an object in an array in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am building a swipeable card in React. The card contains 4 slides. The values displayed in the card rely on the user input.

First I am defining a sample object like this:

```
const initialState = { id: '', title: '', name: '', image: ''};
```

Inside my component, I am defining the array state like:

```
const [card, setCard] = useState([initialState]);
```

I am displaying the card side by side along with the user input fields for users to view the cards as they compose. So whenever the user adds/edits a specific value of the card he can view it live on the card.

We can set the state of an object for each field like this:

```
<Input id='title' name='title' placeholder="Enter Title" type='text' value={card.title} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Handle Change function:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
        setCard({ ...card, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
```

But this is not possible for the above-mentioned array of objects. So how to handle this situation?
Whenever a user swipes the previous/next card the fields must be populated with the appropriate values so that he can edit them. Simply, a user must be able to edit any field at any time. Whenever a user adds a new card a new object must be pushed to the array state.

Full code:

```
const initialState = { id: '', title: '', name: '', image: ''};

const Home = () => {
    const [card, setCard] = useState([initialState]);
    const isdisabled = true;

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setCard({ ...card, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    const handleAdd = () => {
        //TODO
    }

    return (
        <Flex>
            <Center>
                <Flex bg="white" w="lg" h="420" borderRadius="lg" m="7" p="2" alignItems="center">
                <Box w="48" align="center">
                        <IconButton aria-label='Go to previous' disabled borderRadius="full" bg='gray.200' color='black' icon={<ChevronLeftIcon w={6} h={6}/>} />
                </Box>

                <Box>
                        <Image src={card[0].image} w="full" h="44" objectFit="cover" objectPosition="0 0" borderRadius="lg" />
                        <Heading color="black" size='lg'>{card[0].title}</Heading>
                        <Text color="black" size='40'>{card[0].namee}</Text>
                      
                    </Box>

                    <Box w="48" align="center">
                        <IconButton aria-label='Go to previous' disabled borderRadius="full" bg='gray.200' color='black' icon={<ChevronRightIcon w={6} h={6}/>} />
                    </Box>
                </Flex>
        </Center>
        <Flex direction="column" w="lg" gap="4" m="7">
            <Input placeholder="Enter Title" value={card[0].title} onChange={handleChange}/>
            <Input placeholder="Enter Name" value={card[0].name} onChange={handleChange}/>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>Upload Image</Button>
            
            <Button onClick={handleAdd}>Add another slide</Button>
            <Button colorScheme="blue">Done</Button>
        </Flex>
       </Flex>
    )
}

export default Home
```

How to seamlessly do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the event target's name and value? How do these fit with the `initialState` object shape? Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for all the relevant code you're trying to work with?

Comment: You have an initial state which is an array with one object. And you're trying to update that state (an array) as an object.

Comment: Are you trying to edit a specific element in the `card` state, or add an element to the state? It's not clear. Can you provide a complete and reproducible example, and more clearly explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Andy is it wrong? I have defined a sample object since this is what all the card is going to looklike.

Comment: @DrewReese I am making a card with 4 slides. Every slide display items like title, image, and name. All those values are user entered. A user must be able to add 4 slides. And he can edit whatever field he wants. How to handle this with state hooks?

Comment: Right, that much you already said. Please share the code being used to render a card with 4 slides.

Comment: @DrewReese I haven't worked it out yet since I am struggling with this problem.

Comment: My idea is to map the array state whenever a user clicks on a button to add a new slide.

Comment: That's the part that doesn't make any sense yet for the code you've shared so far. If you wanted to edit a specific card then I'd expect to map the existing card state to a new array, updating a specific index/element object by input name and value, ***but*** if you are trying to add a new slide I'd expect the new object to be appended to the array and match the object shape of the `initialState` object. Does this make sense? If you could provide a complete example then we may be able to just figure it out for ourselves what you are trying to do with the code.

Comment: @DrewReese I've added the full code. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gabriele Petrioli's answer is the perfect solution to my problem except it needs a little tweaking:

Add `activeCardIndex` to both navigation handlers' dependency list:

```
    const handleGotoNext = useCallback(() => {
        // you need to also handle not allowing to go beyond the max
        if(activeCardIndex < cards.length-1){
            setActiveCardIndex(prevActive => prevActive + 1);
        }
      }, [activeCardIndex]);
      
    const handleGotoPrevious = useCallback(() => {
    // you need to also handle not allowing to go below 0
        if(activeCardIndex > 0){
            setActiveCardIndex(prevActive => prevActive - 1);
        }
    }, [activeCardIndex]);
```

And the `handleChange` function:

```
    const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
        setCards(prevCards => prevCards.map((card, index) => {
          if (index === activeCardIndex) {
            return { ...card,
              [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
          }else {
              return card;
          }
        }));
    }, [activeCardIndex]);
```

Answer (score 1):

your card state is array of objects need to update array first object

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const arr = [...card]
     arr[0] = {...arr[0], [e.target.name]: e.target.value } 
     setCard(arr);
  }
```

Comment: This will only edit the first object of the array right?

Answer (score 1):

You would likely need an additional state variable, specifying the active card

something like

```js
const [cards, setCards] = useState([initialState]);
const [activeCardIndex, setActiveCardIndex] = useState(0);

handleGotoNext = useCallback(() => {
  // you need to also handle not allowing to go beyond the max
  setActiveCardIndex(prevActive => prevActive + 1);
}, []);

const handleGotoPrevious = useCallback(() => {
  // you need to also handle not allowing to go below 0
  setActiveCardIndex(prevActive => prevActive - 1);
}, []);

const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
  setCards(prevCards => prevCards.map((card, index) => {
    if (index === activeCardIndex) {
      return { ...card,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    }
    return card;
  }));
}, [activeCardIndex]);

const handleAdd = useCallback(() => {
  const newCards = [...cards, { ...initialState
  }];
  setCards(newCards);
  setActiveCardIndex(newCards.length - 1);
}, [cards]);
const activeCard = cards[activeCardIndex];

// for the rendering you should use the activeCard constant, instead of cards[n]
return (
   <Flex>
   ...
     <Image src={activeCard.image} w="full" h="44" objectFit="cover" objectPosition="0 0" borderRadius="lg" />
   ...
   </Flex>
)
```

Comment: This looks neat. Thank you for this. How will you push new object into this state if user add a slide?

Comment: @Nithur added an update with a sample `handleAdd` implementation.

Comment: I've tried your code. The changes in the input field isn't rendering as expected. Should I need to pass any parameters in the handlechange function?

Comment: @Nithur my mistake. You need to add `activeCardIndex` in the dependency list of the `useCallback` since we use it inside the function. Updated the code.

Comment: The same issue persists.

Comment: @Nithur i see that your `Input` elements do not have a `name` atrtribute. They need one since you are using it to set the relevant property when updating. They should be like `<Input name="title" placeholder="Enter Title"...` and `<Input name="name" placeholder="Enter Name"..` etc.

Comment: Oh, sh*t! how dumb I am. Sorry, I didn't notice it. There is one more concern - when I add a new slide and go back to previous slide, the app stops with an error: ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')```

Comment: @Nithur I think this could happen when you are at `0` add a new catrd and then press back. That is because the code currently does not take you to the new one when adding a card. Will update the code

Comment: @Nithur updated the `handleAdd` method.

Comment: ```handlechange``` function in your code only returns the edited object of the array. Every other object becomes undefined. How to change that to return the whole array?

Comment: @Nithur, you are so right, updated answer. Sorry for this, i had no live environment to test it.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Gabriele. I've figured it out and wrote the answer here. Also, you need to add ```activeCardIndex``` to the dependency list of previous and next event handlers.

Comment: @Nithur that is only needed if you use that variable in the function code. In your answer where you use it, you are correct to add it.